# SQL Server Join between two unique columns poor performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that is taking a long time to execute.

```
SELECT
    Table1.A, Table1.B, Table2.C
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2
        ON Table1.UniqueCol = Table2.UniqueCol
WHERE
    Table1.UniqueCol = @storedProcParam
```

Both tables have a unique nonclustered index on UniqueCol which is a varchar(64) but neither has it as its primary key.  One of the tables has a few million records and the other has a few thousand.  Is it the fact that the column is a varchar(64) that is holding back performance, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Assuming you have an index on the `UniqueCol` field, how is the `@storedProcParam` defined?  Is it defined as a parameter to a stored procedure or a local variable in the stored procedure.  I've seen better performance on query cache of the execution plan when using a local variable vs. a passed in variable.  Not much else to go by though...

Comment: Does the query run better with a hard coded value vs. the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from some external issue such as blocking the only reason that springs to mind would be if the parameter was of a higher precedence datatype that causes an implicit cast and prevents a simple index seek on the two tables (using the [implied predicate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2009/04/28/implied-predicates-and-query-hints.aspx) on table2) and a cross join of the 0 or 1 row result that both sides return.

You say the columns are `varchar`. You would get this scan instead of seek if the parameter was `nvarchar` under some collations.

Comment: I checked the actual execution plan and I see exactly this issue.  I didn't realize one of the tables was nvarchar(64), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The values in your select clause should be included in your non-clustered index. This would allow the engine to use the index exclusively instead of having to go to your clustered index. Have you rebuilt your clustered and/or non-clustered indexes recently? Do you know if your indexes are highly fragmented? Can you please post your actual execution plan?